# Imposible to enroll Windows 10 in intune when devices already in Azure AD

Tags: windows, azure, intune

My problem is that I already have all my Windows10 devices in AzureAD. I upload to AAD using AD Connect from my Classic AD, so now I have hybrid devices in AAD. But I need to manage them with Intune. How can I get those device in Intune. Now all my devices have MDM in status None and owner N/A.
I don't see how can I get them into Intune. I'm trying with a Enterprise Mobility + Security E5 license

Answer (score 1):

Although this thread may be a bit older...

if you already have your devices as Hybrid Joined in `Azure AD` by syncing them with `Azure AD Connect`, you can automatically enroll them to `Intune` by using the `MDM GPO` (`ADMX` template must fit to the version of `Windows 10` i.e. 1903, 1909, etc. used in your environment).

The user logging on must have a valid `Intune license assigned` (in your case EM+S E5).

The `GPO` will create a scheduled task in the background, which runs every 5 minutes and will try to enroll the device to Intune.

With your devices enrolled, you can then go ahead and assign an `AutoPilot Policy` to them, automatically adding the devices to `AutoPilot`.

> Here's a link to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/enroll-a-windows-10-device-automatically-using-group-policy) for this method.

Best Regards,
Fred